# How to bulk upload 100+ users to a single gitlab group at once?

Tags: gitlab, usergroups

I have to create new groups and add new users to the respective groups every week. Adding them one by one is tiresome. Anyway I can bulk upload the users? I have their username and the email id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use gitlab users api

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html

You can easily create new users

> Creates a new user. Note only administrators can create new users. Either password or reset_password should be specified (reset_password takes priority).

```
POST /users
```

Parameters:

- email (required)
- Emailpassword (optional)
- Passwordreset_password (optional) -
  Send user password reset link - true or false(default)
- username (required)
- Usernamename (required) - real name
- ...